# Обработка кириллицы при разборе url?

Tags: javascript, jquery

В запросе url есть кирилица: прм.: /?s=билеты+на+самолет, я его разбираю создавая ссылку и вытягивая нужнуюю мне часть, но получаю трабл с кодировкой.

```
var searchurl = $(location).attr('href');
var a = $('<a>' , {
    href: searchurl,
});

$('#localsearch-inpt').val(a.prop('search').substring(3));

var currentQuery = $('#localsearch-inpt').val();

updateSearchedData(currentQuery);
```

currentQuery при наличии кирилицы в запросе выдает что-то вроде такого: %d0%b1%d0%b8...

Comment: Встречался с подобной бедой, не смог найти ответа. Видимо пока что это такая спецификация JS. И нужно пилить новую билеотеку, под такие методы.

Comment: Есть ответ на этот вопрос ) decodeURI()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[decodeURI()](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/decodeURI)

```
decodeURI("https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/JavaScript_%D1%88%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%BB%D1%8B");
// "https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/JavaScript_шеллы"
```

Comment: Я его в вначале пробовал, но для searchurl , а сейчас сделал для a.prop('search') и все четко. Спасибо.